# Local complexity of tilings under substitutions

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, tiling

I am trying to read [this survey](http://wms.mat.agh.edu.pl/%7Esem_ds/abstract/nr_1.pdf) of E. Arthur Robinson, about tilings of $\mathbb{R}^d$. I have some familiarity with 'symbolic' tilings, but I don't think I have a good intuition on 'geometric' tilings.  For that reason I will appreciate help in verifying some facts.

I was wondering about the property of *$2$-patch closure* given in definition $4.6$. i.e.,

$$ S\big( \mathcal{T}^{(2)} \big)\subseteq \mathcal{T}^* $$

where $S=LC$ is a tiling substitution on $\mathcal{T}$ and $X_{\mathcal{T}}$ has finite local complexity.

I was wondering whether this means that for all tiling $x\in X_{\mathcal{T}}$, it must be that $S^n(x)\in X_{\mathcal{T}}$ and that the $2$-patches occurring in $S^n(x)$ are in $\mathcal{T}^{(2)}$ ? Or is it perhaps possible to see infinitely many $2$-patches when considering the  $ S^n(x) $ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

I was also wondering whether most substitutions over tiles with an *edge-to-edge* condition satisfy the $2$-patch closure property?
I am asking this since Robinson assumes from that point onwards that all substitutions satisfy this property. So, I was wondering how restrictive an assumption is this?

Thanks in advance to any responders.